How to track the price or market cap of spl tokens?
I am creating a python bot that receives a market cap token through the api
at the moment, I have implemented code that receives a market cap token that was recently created through pumpfun, via a web socket
but I ran into the problem that I can't do the same with the token if it got on raydium, and I do not know if it will work the same way as with pump fun
Has anyone ever done this? is there a similar solution for raydium?
I would be extremely grateful if someone would help me.

according to the documentation, there is a parameter included in the query response called lamports. Lamports will tell you the "market cap" of the AccountInfo you are looking for.
Also, I think you should check this out, as you want to simply query information from the network.
I hope this helped.
Cheers

can I ask you to show me an example of python code implementation?
